# How to mask PII data i.e. email in application insights from logging

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api, telemetry

I want to mask email id data being logged in HTPP dependency. I have written a my telemetry initializer as below. Can you please let me know how to configure this so it will be masked while logging.

```
public class MaskingTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (item is RequestTelemetry)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = (RequestTelemetry)item;
            var filteredUrl = ReplaceEmailWithMaskValue(requestTelemetry.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            requestTelemetry.Name = filteredUrl;
            requestTelemetry.Url = new Uri(filteredUrl);
        }
        else if (item is DependencyTelemetry)
        {
            var dependencyTelemetry = (DependencyTelemetry)item;
            if (dependencyTelemetry?.Name?.ToLower()?.Contains("get") == true)
            {
                dependencyTelemetry.Name = ReplaceEmailWithMaskValue(dependencyTelemetry.Name);
                dependencyTelemetry.Data = ReplaceEmailWithMaskValue(dependencyTelemetry.Data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have resolved issue by referring this documents.                     
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved, please refer to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling